# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\Users\xampp\htdocs\PHP_Login_Script\config.php on line 6

I'm getting this error above on localhost even if my config file is like this:

```
<?php

    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB_DATABASE", "databasename");

    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
```

This used to work, but now it doesn't anymore. Is there any problem with this code or is it not working now?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That combination of username, host, and password is not allowed to connect to the server. Verify the permission tables (reloading grants if required) on the server and that you're connecting to the correct server.

Comment: sir im only using local host and i have root as username and a blank password..i dont see anything wrong with it because before it is working is it obsolete?that way of coding that is why it is not working?using localhost is like that and root and blank password is always accepted

Comment: Your server says otherwise.

Comment: wait let me check again on how to connect to local host just to be sure il be back on you

Comment: Make sure that your password doesn't have special characters and just keep a plain password (for ex: 12345), it will work. This is the strangest thing that I have ever seen. I spent about 2 hours to figure this out.

Comment: @Sathya is right.  Don't use cpanel's method of generating a password - apparently some special characters don't work.  It took me the same 2 hours - then I found the above comment...

Comment: In my case, I've selected "locally access only" on the server. Sp I did not have permission. Just set it to any Host and voila.

Comment: Great, thanks Nacho, I saved those two hours.

Comment: Thank you so so much @Sathya and Chiwda 
I was pulling my hairs till I reached your comments

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that your password doesn't have special characters and just keep a plain password (for ex: 12345), it will work. This is the strangest thing that I have ever seen. I spent about 2 hours to figure this out.

Note: 12345 mentioned below is your plain password

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'yourusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
```

Comment: While this answer is the most correct, specifically do no use 12345 since it is one of the top 10 most used passwords in the world, but do keep your password alphanumeric. By adding just a few extra characters something like 'smJ4bJ39kHab29PpfjKq' can still provide equal or better entropy as those cPanel randomly generated passwords, while still excluding special characters.

Comment: don't know why this happened for one server, similar password worked in the other server, good catch by the way!! it solved the problem.

Comment: I CANNOT believe that this worked, but it did and ended the madness I've been going through for the past 3+ hours! Alphanumeric passwords FTW!!

Answer (score 15):

If youre running wamp update

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
```

To your machines ip address (mine is 192.168.0.25);

```
define("DB_HOST", "192.168.0.25");
```

You can find it on window by typing ipconfig in your console or ifconfig on mac/linux

Comment: On WAMP, one also need to make sure that PHP is connecting to mySQL only. By default it will connect to MariaDB. It can be changed from WAMP tray icon by changing default SQL server to mySQL.

Comment: Had to do this on my local Mac in OSX too. Didnt work with localhost. Had to enter 127.0.0.1 instead.

Answer (score 11):

mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

use DB_HOST instead of DB_SERVER

Comment: why? What difference does it make how one calls their vars or constants?

Comment: In the question the user passed the wrong constant names.

Answer (score 9):

Look at your code 
You defined DB_HOST and querying DB_SERVER. DB_USER and DB_USERNAME
Use this code

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "databasename");

$connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER , DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
```

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed a few things here, the "DB_HOST" defined here should be also DB_HOST down there, and the "DB_USER" is called "DB_USER" down there too, check the code always that those are the same.

```
<?php
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB_DATABASE", "");

    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

you defIne as DB_USER but use as DB_USERNAME. Also php says username@localhost cant access. Not root@localhost.

Change your define or connect paramater.

Answer (score 2):

This is your code:

```
<?php

    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB_DATABASE", "databasename");

    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

?>
```

The only error that causes this message is that:

1. you're defining a `DB_USER` but you're calling after as `DB_USERNAME`.

Please be more careful next time.

It is better for an entry-level programmer that wants to start coding in `PHP` not to use what he or she does not know very well.

ONLY as advice, please try to use (for the first time) code more ubiquitous.

ex: do not use the `define()` statement, try to use variables declaration as `$db_user = 'root';`

Have a nice experience :)

Answer (score 2):

The same issue faced me with XAMPP 7 and opencart Arabic 3. 
Replacing  localhost by the actual machine name reslove the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Use this** 
After setup this you will not receive this issue again

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('your_root_password');
```

I was stuck up in this issue after used this query everything was solved

Answer (score 2):

Try the above answers 90% of the time this will be you issue. For me my problem was that my database password had a $ in it.

```
$servername = '127.0.0.1';
$username = 'user_bob';
$password = 'sdfasdf$B';

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, 'any_database');

//DO NOT USE DOUBLE QUOTES;
//$password = "sdfasdf$B";
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem occurd with me, with AWS RDS MySQL. Just now, [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42503116/5536094) similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32919571/5536094) here. Looked various sources, but as of this thread, almost all lack of answer.
While this thread helped me, tweak in mind to update hostnames at server. Access your SSH and follow the steps:

```
cd /etc/
sudo nano hosts
```

**Now, Appending here your hostnames:** For example:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 subdomain.domain.com [if cname redirected to endpoints]
127.0.0.1 xxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com [Endpoints]
```

and now, configuring `config/database.php` as follows:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '35.150.12.345',
    'username' => 'user-name-here',
    'password' => 'password-here',
    'database' => 'database-name-here',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

where `35.150.12.345` is your *IPv4 Public IP*, located at `ec2-dashboard > Network Interfaces > Description : RDSNetworkInterface >> IPv4 Public` IP('35.150.12.345') there.

**Note: Please note that only IPV4 will work at 'hostname' option. hostname, cname, domains will output database connection error.**

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered above, Just to make you feel comfortable using all four string at the same time in a connection

```
<?php
  define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
  define("DB_USER", "root");
  define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
  define("DB_DATABASE", "databasename");

  $db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
  // you could test connection eventually using a if and else conditional statement, 
  // feel free to take out the code below once you see Connected!
  if ($db) {
    echo "Connected!";
  } else {
    echo "Connection Failed";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error trying to connect with a different user than `root` I'd set up to limit access.

In mysql I'd set up user `MofX` with host `%` and it wouldn't connect.

When I changed the user's host to `127.0.0.1`, as in 'MofX'@'127.0.0.1', it worked.

Comment: I was using MAMP on MacOs and replacing 'localhost' by '127.0.0.1' resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For somebody use XAMPP 8. Actually XAMPP install MySQL in VM, so connect it via IP address show in XAMPP. There is no MySQL server on localhost.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error in define arguments, change **DB_HOST** into **DB_SERVER** and **DB_USER** into **DB_USERNAME**:

```
<?php

    define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
    define("DB_USERNAME", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB_DATABASE", "databasename");
    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was:

```
define ('DB_PASSWORD', "MyPassw0rd!'");
```

(the odd single ' before the double ")

Answer (score 0):

Not that anyone would ever have CAPS on when entering a password...but it can give this error.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a number of reasons. In my case, I just needed to change the port. You can do so by specifying it after a colon when defining DB_HOST.

`define( 'DB_HOST', localhost:3308  )`

Answer (score 0):

In the privileges section of the database in phpmyadmin, make sure to use the privileged user and password. My default user is "root" and no password. I got this problem since i was searching in w3schools and copy pasted the whole script in and find out that's the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what solved my problem:

Open config.inc.php

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'something';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

This is what part of the file looks like. I removed the password and then was able to log in to localhost/myphpadmin (the place that gave me this error). You might have the issue from somewhere else like trying to go to adminer.

I got this issue because I reinstalled and recopied files so things got messed up. I went an removed the password, accessed myphpadmin and set the password to the database from there and readded the files like above.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have two connections at the same time? If so, close every time you don't need it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

Put " DB_HOST " instead of " DB_SERVER " also 
put " DB_USER " Instead of " DB_USERNAME "
```

than it working fine !

Answer (score -2):

try

```
define("DB_PASSWORD", null);
```

and those are warnings 
try

```
$db = @mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
```

But i will recommend you to set a root password

Answer (score -2):

Try changing:

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
```

to this:

```
define("DB_SERVER", "127.0.0.1");
```