# php establishing connection with mysql database

Tags: php

Hello everyone am trying to connect to MySQL database but getting this error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Error: Could not establish connection.Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
>        Here is my code:

```
 <?php        
    $host = "localhost";
    $db   = "resumedb";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "sa";        

$phpConnect = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $db, $password);
    //checking the if connection.    
 if($phpConnect === false)
   {
      die("Error: Could not establish connection.".mysqli_connect_error());
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysqli\_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174183/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernameloca)

Comment: Please I appreciate any help from any one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly was unclear about the error message?

Comment: Error It self giving the Answer that "User Root is not authorized to access the database you are trying to connect."

Comment: Make sure the db credentials are correct and working.

Comment: I can't tell you how bad this would be on a production database, please create a user with access only to this db. You could give your user access from any location. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `resumedb` . * TO 'dbuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION ;

Comment: Thanks to every one out there for your contributions the connection has just been established after granting access  in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax is:`mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd")`

so try:

```
$phpConnect = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
```

[refer this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: Thank so much for your help, but this doesn't work as well.

Comment: this is what the syntax is now check the values you are passing and with same try to login from phpmyadmin.

Comment: am actually new to php and am using Xamp to work with phpstorm I can not find how to login with phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Basically If you are the newbee in PHP so you should
 
    1.first start the Xamp/Wamp service.
    2.else db credentials for password should be  $password = "".

Comment: The Xamp is on already  and Apache and MySQL is running already.