# MySQL Database not connecting with name

Tags: php, mysqli

Whenever I try to connect to my database with my credentials, it doesn't connect with the username, for example when I try to connect to my local database with

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","","database")
```

It returns

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'database'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: mysqli\_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174183/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernameloca)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't connect using all four parameters on `mysqli_connect()`
From the above code i can tell your

```
host : "localhost"
user: "dbuser"
password: ""
database name: "database"
```

Do this,

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbuser", "");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "database");
// to check if you're connected, after tested and see you can take off the code below...
if ($conn) {
  echo "Connected";
} else {
  echo "Connection failed";
}
```

if you seriously want to connect using all four parameter above?

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","dbuser","","database");
// to check if you're connected, after tested and see you can take off the code below...
if ($conn) {
  echo "Connected";
} else {
  echo "Failed";
}
```

Hope this was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a space between the quotes like this " " instead of "" to show as blank in the password value in your query because in programming a value either 0(false) or 1(true) has to be there you cannot have nothing and expect something

This is when you have not set password for the user in your local phpmyadmin like root user and also check for spelling mistakes