# SQL ERROR [ mysqli ] Access denied for user 'abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES) [1045]

Tags: php, mysqli, phpbb

i am getting this error as i integrate this forum in my website i am new to this error his is my **config.php** i had made changes according to my database i am new to this i don't know why and what is this error.

```
   <?php
    $dbms = 'phpbb\\db\\driver\\mysqli';
    $db host = 'localhost';
    $dbport = '';
    $dbname = 'abc_forum';
    $dbuser = 'root',
    $dbpasswd = '';
    $table_prefix = '';
    $phpbb_adm_relative_path ='adm/';
    $acm_type = 'phpbb\\cache\\driver\\file';
    @define('PHPBB_INSTALLED', true);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that is throwing the error? Where you're actually executing the connections

Comment: https://www.phpbb.com/support/docs/en/3.1/kb/article/rebuilding-your-configphp-file/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: mysqli\_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174183/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernameloca)

Comment: you should have a call to mysqli_connect() somewhere. It apparently isn't using the config values.

Answer (score 1):

change $db host to $dbhost :

```
<?php
    $dbms = 'phpbb\\db\\driver\\mysqli';
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbport = '';
    $dbname = 'abc_forum';
    $dbuser = 'root',
    $dbpasswd = '';
    $table_prefix = '';
    $phpbb_adm_relative_path ='adm/';
    $acm_type = 'phpbb\\cache\\driver\\file';
    @define('PHPBB_INSTALLED', true);
```

Comment: Wow I didn't saw that one! lol nice. He has a space between db and host: 
 Like $db host

Comment: i see no way that could have caused the error he reported.

Answer (score -1):

The username and password are not valid. That is what this means. Ask your hosting provider for the correct credentials.

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple

`$conn = new mysqli("DB_HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE");`

Comment: Who downvoted? Do you have any reason for it.? Nothing is wrong or hard.  I was try to simple the code.

Comment: Its not my downvote, but possibly because phpBB uses its own database abstraction layer, and that should be used.