# When i created my android app and opened , it shown me api run timeout

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk

[It shown me api run timeout when i opened my android app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTFl0.png)

my coding

```
<?php
    
    // Turn off error reporting
    //error_reporting(1);
    
    
    //web API path
    //eg http://Hanshu01.com/API/
    $API_path="http://Hanshu01.com/API/";
    
    //this is firebase server key to send push notications
    
    // check how you can get firebase server key  https://i.gyazo.com/7c3f23a30c14d3008533605a9821f944.png
    define("AAAAv6B2Q40:APA91bGljMuyrvM5OSe3xHkIRiFyBXZ2l2bgQ4_oPmxqxuGrRk-pgZ2ovmcjQ1U2mMvVZUK8sF_-swL7IlUkNi_qEfGI5XriAnPEAR9tRabIWzG4pgq01_c12OzrbUKtDa3oT0oYqN10");
    
    
    
    //database configration
    $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "hanshuco_TikTokIndia";
    $username = "hanshuco_TikTokIndia";
    $password = "5FDk}64z6iPA

";
    
    // Create connection

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    mysqli_query($conn,"SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'");
    
    // Check connection

    if (!$conn) {

        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

    }
    
    
?>
```

My error

```
[09-Jul-2020 08:11:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/hanshuco/public_html/API/config.php on line 14
[09-Jul-2020 08:11:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'hanshuco_TikTokIndia'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/hanshuco/public_html/API/config.php on line 28
[09-Jul-2020 08:11:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/hanshuco/public_html/API/config.php on line 29
[09-Jul-2020 08:15:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/hanshuco/public_html/API/config.php on line 14
[09-Jul-2020 08:15:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'hanshuco_TikTokIndia'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/hanshuco/public_html/API/config.php on line 28
[09-Jul-2020 08:15:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/hanshuco/public_html/API/config.php on line 29
```

Comment: This is not an android app. This is PHP and Mysql. It says you have an issue connecting to MySQL server as the credentials are incorrect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: mysqli\_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174183/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernameloca)

Answer (score 0):

public class ApiRequest {

```
public static void Call_Api (final Context context, String url, JSONObject jsonObject,
                             final Callback callback){

    final String [] urlsplit=url.split("/");
    Log.d(Variables.tag,urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1]);

    if(jsonObject!=null)
    Log.d(Variables.tag+urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1],jsonObject.toString());

     JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Log.d(Variables.tag+urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1],response.toString());

                    if(callback!=null)
                    callback .Responce(response.toString());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           Log.d(Variables.tag+urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1],error.toString());
           // Toast.makeText(context, "Api run timeout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(callback!=null)
              callback .Responce(error.toString());

        }
    });




    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(600000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);






      }
```

}