# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to connect my database with this statement:

```
<?php
//database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'shira-23');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '1234');
define('DB_NAME', 'mydb');

//get connection
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die('Not connected : Ah sh*t ' . mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

and get this warning:

> mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'shira-23'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: mysqli\_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174183/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernameloca)

Comment: Did you try to set define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); without the port number ?

Comment: Have you checked if the user `shira-23` has the right for database `mydb` ?

Comment: i think wrong password or username