# Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) This is the problem im dealing with

Tags: php, database

[image]

> this is my code. when I remove the numbers inside the password the program runs just fine. is it okay to leave it without a password?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: mysqli\_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174183/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernameloca)

Answer (score 0):

If you get the `Access denied for..` when entering `123` as password and you don't get it when removing `123` in your password field it probably means your database user `root` doesn't have a password.