# How to connect the docker phpmyadmin image to the .env file credential?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

My newly cloned project can't log in to PHPMyAdmin on my personal laptop, but my office PC are working fine.

This is my `docker-composer.yml`:

I added an image for the phpmyadmin but when you redirect to the login page and enter the db credential it's not working

```
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3307'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        environment:
            - PMA_HOST=mysql
            - PMA_PORT=3306
            - PMA_PASSWORD='${DB_PASSWORD}'
        networks:
            - sail
        ports:
            - 8001:80
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-mariadb:
        driver: local
```

[image]

Then this is my `.env` file:

```
APP_NAME=recruitment
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:JfiPosjWIXm2TMswb5zRTw6/d9+fwBAByZ5Z8igjik0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=phnavy_recruitment
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=no.replyonlinerecruitment@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=ihmdshzxgqpzrxdv
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no.replyonlinerecruitment@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://meilisearch:7700
```

my laravel version in this project is laravel 8

I hope you can help me with this one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to the screenshot, it's hy000-1045. So not the networking issue. You get this answer from running MySQL.
It looks like your user does not exist or does not have enough grants. This should help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174183/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernameloca

Comment: I don't see any mention of the `.env` file in your docker-compose.  What makes that file relevant?

Comment: @erik258 when I run the command `php artisan sail:install` it overwritten the `.env` file

Answer (score 0):

working version

```php
    environment:
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
          - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

```php
phpmyadmin:
        links:
            - mysql:db
        ..........
```